# Setting environment variables inside PHP unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, environment-variables, gitlab, shell-exec

I'm doing some basic unit testing on a utility function I made years ago but it involves accessing the `$_SERVER` array.

Since my unit tests are run from the command line, I have to manually set the values of the array myself.

This works well using GitLab Runners because on the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I just do something like:

```
before_script:
  - export SERVER_PORT="80"
  - export SERVER_NAME="gitlab"
```

My test is currently unable to test all statements from that function as it checks for the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` value.

### Unit Test

```
public function testGetEnvironment() {
    shell_exec('set SERVER_NAME="localhost"');
    $this->assertEquals("localhost", $this->util->get_environment());

    shell_exec('set SERVER_NAME="gitlab"');
    $this->assertEquals("gitlab", $this->util->get_environment());
}
```

**NOTE:** I had to use `set` as I am on a Windows machine while our GitLab Runner is on a Linux machine so I used `export` on the `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

I was expecting this test to pass but it seems like the command to set the environment variable using `shell_exec` isn't changing the value at all. I still get the value from what was defined from the YAML file.

### Update

Here's the failure message:

```
1) UtilTest::testGetEnvironment
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'localhost'
+'gitlab'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any shell command you execute would be a separate process and wouldn't affect the running process.
Since you're unit testing how the function would use the `$_SERVER` variable, you don't need to go through all the hassle of thinking how it would be set in a "real" scenario - just manually modify it and test your function:

```
public function testGetEnvironment() {
    $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] = "localhost";
    $this->assertEquals("localhost", $this->util->get_environment());

    $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] = "gitlab";
    $this->assertEquals("gitlab", $this->util->get_environment());
}
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. I over-complicated this one - my bad.. thanks a lot!

Comment: you mean $_SERVER instead of $SERVER, right?

Comment: @Adam oops, yes, good catch. Edited and fixed.